# É possível emparelhar valores de dois dataframes com números de observações diferentes?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho dois data frames:

```
Sexo <- rep(1:2 , length.out = 51)
Estudo <- rep(1: 17, length.out = 51)
Salário <- c(runif(51, min=900, max=3000))

data1 <- data.frame(Sexo, Estudo, Salário)

data2 <-  data.frame(TaxaHomens = c(seq(0.1,0.99,length=17)), 
                TaxaMulheres = c(seq(0.2,0.99,length=17)), 
                Estudo = c(1:17))
```

A variável Sexo em data1 está classificada como 1 para homens e 2 para mulheres, Estudo corresponde aos anos de estudos da pessoa e salário ao ganhos mensais.

É possível criar uma coluna chamada Taxa no primeiro data frame(data1) de forma que as taxas do segundo data frame fiquem organizadas de acordo com Sexo e Estudo?

Exemplificando, quero que na nova coluna de data1 eu tenha para Sexo=1 e Estudo=3 uma taxa de 0.211250, para todas as observações desse tipo e assim por diante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando os pacotes `dplyr` e `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data2 <- data2 %>% 
  gather(Sexo, Taxa, TaxaHomens:TaxaMulheres) 
data2$Sexo <- ifelse(data2$Sexo == "TaxaHomens", 1, 2)
left_join(data1, data2, by = c("Sexo", "Estudo"))
```

O que fiz foi transformar seu `data2` de forma que ficasse apenas com uma coluna de taxa (homens e mulheres na mesma coluna).

Answer (score 0):

Talvez tenha uma maneira mais eficiente, mas se você não tiver muitas linhas não será problema:

```
for(i in 1: dim(data1)[1]) {
  data1$Taxa[i] <- data2[which(data2$Estudo == data1$Estudo[i]), data1$Sexo[i]]
}
```

Comment: Quando uso essa solução no data frame recebo a seguinte resposta: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Desemp", value = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.0559149359202274 : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 362555  --------                            
                             Meu data frame tem mais de 300000 linhas por isso acho que não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando base R:

```
Sexo <- rep(1:2 , length.out = 51)
Estudo <- rep(1: 17, length.out = 51)
Salario <- c(runif(51, min=900, max=3000))

data1 <- data.frame(Sexo, Estudo, Salario)

data2 <-  data.frame(TaxaHomens = c(seq(0.1,0.99,length=17)), 
                TaxaMulheres = c(seq(0.2,0.99,length=17)), 
                Estudo = c(1:17))


data1$Fator = data1$Estudo
data1$Fator = factor(data1$Fator)
levels(data1$Fator) = data2$TaxaHomens
data1$Fator = as.numeric(as.character(data1$Fator))
head(data1)

  Sexo Estudo   Salario    Fator
1    1      1 2287.2813 0.100000
2    2      2 2845.6058 0.155625
3    1      3 2606.5139 0.211250
4    2      4  911.2628 0.266875
5    1      5 2658.2753 0.322500
6    2      6 2082.1462 0.378125
```

O segredo é criar uma coluna de `factors` com os mesmos valores da coluna Estudo e substituir os `levels` pelos valores da coluna TaxaHomens ou TaxaMulheres. Importante que esse jeito só funciona porque em data2 não existem dados duplicados.